# What is an Encoding Number™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, number-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with **Number** version puzzles.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it an **Encoding Number™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Encoding }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Numbers}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  9 }&\text{ 7 }\\ \hline
\text{  10 }&\text{ 8 }\\ \hline
\text{  60 }&\text{ 58 }\\ \hline
\text{  95 }&\text{ 93 }\\ \hline
\text{  193 }&\text{ 191 }\\ \hline
\text{  315 }&\text{ 313 }\\ \hline
\text{  1,034 }&\text{ 1,032 }\\ \hline
\text{  2,194 }&\text{ 2,192 }\\ \hline
\text{  5,979 }&\text{ 5,977 }\\ \hline
\text{  16,466 }&\text{ 16,464 }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Encoding Numbers™,Not Encoding Numbers™
9,7
10,8
60,58
95,93
193,191
315,313
1034,1032
2194,2192
5979,5977
16466,16464
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Hint 2:

> [image]

Comment: is it time for a clue yet?

Comment: I found the thing in the clue but I have no clue what to do with this information now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encoding numbers are obtained as follows

> Take a number written in English and convert it to morse code, without spaces.
>  **ONE** $\rightarrow$ ----..
>  Convert the morse code to binary with the rule dash=1, dot=0.
>  ----.. $\rightarrow$ 111100
>  Convert the binary number to decimal
>  111100 $\rightarrow$ 60
>  The Encoding Numbers are those which are obtained at the end of this process.

Specific Examples

> **SIX** $\rightarrow$ 9
>  **SEVEN** and **TEN** $\rightarrow$ 10
>  **ONE** $\rightarrow$ 60
>  **TWO** $\rightarrow$ 95
>  **EIGHT** $\rightarrow$ 193
>  **SIXTY** $\rightarrow$ 315
>  **ELEVEN** $\rightarrow$ 1034
>  **NINETEEN** $\rightarrow$ 2194
>  **FORTY** $\rightarrow$ 5979
>  **THIRTEEN** $\rightarrow$ 16466

Hint 1

> These characters are called "Dash" and "Dot" which clues to Morse Code.

Hint 2

> These are notes on a piano indicating a transition **B** to **D** (standing for **B**inary to **D**ecimal, the second part of the process)

Comment: Nice work! I think this puzzle is really hard without hints... contains multiple encoding processes.

Comment: @Conifers yes without, at least, the first hint I would never have gotten it.

Answer (score -5):

> not encoded + 2 = encoded

I hope this is the first from a long series.

Comment: You need to find the property... The same difference picked is for the neatness (and yes checked they are all not Encoding Numbers.)

Comment: Hi Lidaranis - with this type of puzzle you're looking for the connection between the *Encoded* numbers in the first column - not a connection between the two numbers in each row. Every number in the first column follows a particular rule, which every number in the second column flouts. Your objective is to find that rule. Try again! :)

Comment: @Conifers you call it neat, I would call it Confusing.

Comment: @Stiv so basically he could have just provided a list of numbers and ask us to find the rule they follow.. avoiding all the.. "neatness"

Comment: @Lidaranis I could give any arbitrary Not Encoding Numbers if the number flouts the property... And the difference could be the another hint for this puzzle :)

Comment: @Lidaranis This puzzle is also the inspiration of the Word version puzzles. The original contains 2 columns where 2nd is representing "Not". Keep going!

Comment: @Lidaranis This is one of the 'What is a ___ Number?' series, which there have been quite a few of on this site (see [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+a+number)). Take a look at a few of them and get a feel for what they're about - that will make it easier to tackle them :)

Comment: @Stiv I understand it now. The others have some extra explanation that is missing in this one. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome :) Happy puzzling!